# Java timezone ids are case-sensitive or platform dependent

Tags: java, timezone

On my mac the following code works correctly and returns a pacific timezone

```
TimeZone pacificTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("america/los_angeles");
```

However on my ubuntu machine Java is not able to parse it and the variable pacificTime returns the GMT timezone. Can someone explain why this happens?

Comment: I take it you're using Java 8; can you specify the exact versions you are using, both on Mac OS X and Ubuntu?

Comment: FYI - In the general case, across all the various platforms and libraries that use them, IANA/Olson time zone IDs should be treated as **case sensitive**.

Comment: Yes and that is why I am surprised it works on mac. I think the library refers to some OS services and mac's OS is somehow supporting lower case while ubuntu is not.

Answer (score 3):

My assumption is that your `Ubuntu` machine runs `Java 8`, while your `mac` runs `Java 7`.

The code works on your `mac`, because the method in `Java 7` is not case sensitive, while in `Java 8` it **is**. For this reason the timezone on your `Ubuntu` machine is simply not recognized and the method returns the default timezone, which is `GMT`.

In order to get the correct timezone on your `Ubuntu`, use the proper name of the timezone, which starts with an uppercase letter:

```
TimeZone pacificTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
```

Comment: Do you have a source for this (breaking) change in Java 8?

Comment: I am using Java 7 on both Ubuntu and mac.